# Using double quotes to define field alias is the best solution?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2008-r2

I create at runtime a query (with my Delphi Application) thet I then execute with

```
EXEC (MyRunTimeGeneratedQuery)
```

One example is this:

```
SELECT
1977 AS [[Employee] Year Of Birth],
'Marc' AS [[Employee] Name]
```

one DB Field contains "[Employee] Date Of Birth", so in the resulting query i have a double "]", this gives a syntax error. SQL Server after the "]" that follows "Employee" is expectring ",".

I found that a solution is using double quotes to enclose all the field alias:

```
SELECT
1977 AS "[Employee] Year Of Birth",
'Marc' AS "[Employee] Name"
```

Is this a reliable solution? Which are the drawbacks if any? (this is my question!)

Another solution I can think of is not to allow the user to store "]", so that

"[Employee] Date Of Birth"

will probably become

"(Employee) Date Of Birth"

Comment: Are you using parameters?

Comment: I tipically use query with parameters with DB Controls, in this case i simply populate a dataset with a query so it is full of name/value data and then i parse it to populate my UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `"` as an enclosing character for the field alias may lead to the same problem, if there is possibility of having `"` in the alias name, e.g. the alias `"Employee" Year Of Birth`, I suppose will result to query formed as:

```
SELECT
    1977 AS ""Employee" Year Of Birth",
-- etc.
```

which is wrong syntactically.

I think that the right thing to do is quote an alias name. If you use `"` as an alias enclosing character, you should double each `"` in the original alias name, when composing query. If you use `[` and `]` you should double each `]` in the original alias name.

Function `quotename` will do the same for you (along with enclosing alias to `[` and `]`), but you can't use it as:

```
SELECT
    1977 AS quotename('[Employee] Year Of Birth'),
-- etc.
```

If you wish to use `quotename`, it should be done before composing query (unless `quotename` itself is a part of query).